# Ionic Cordova App Not Installing on Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm fairly certain the issue persists on all Android devices. However I can be wrong.

I get through the build process with no errors. I find the APK file in the proper folder but when I upload it via USB (not through CLI adb) to my Android (Galaxy S7 edge) it says "App not Installed" after having it go through trying to Install. I am not sure this has anything to do with the processor on my phone as I ran into a similar issue when installing apps made with RPG Maker MV. Right now I'm just (re)trying my hand on Android dev using ionic / Cordova rather than standard Java based Android development.

Note:
I already have debug mode / unknown sources checked.
The app itself works fine in web browser testing.

So main question:
How do I get it to install?

Side question:
Is there a way to tell ionic what version of Android I want to build for?
(I have a few of the SDKs installed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OP's Feedback**

```
cordova run android --device
```

**Original Answer**

1. You need to create a debug version of `apk` using below `CLI` command.

   ```
   ionic run android --device
   ```
2. Plug a device to the PC using USB
3. Copy the `android-debug.apk` file to the device(apk path:.. `\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk`)
4. After that, You have to enable below setting on your Android device.

> settings --> general tab --> security --> unknown sources (enabled
>   this)

5. After that just double-clicked the `android-debug.apk` from the location which you have copied.Then your app will be installed on your device.

Comment: I have unknown sources checked already from a previous encounter using APK's from RPG Maker MV. So its not that so much. -- Editing body.

Comment: Lets see where that android-debug.apk is. Do you know what folder it generates in because I put the cli code in but I cant find it the usual place it should be.

Comment: Derp sorry, Its still not there after running: ionic run android --device

Comment: maybe you're building the wrong project? That is the default path for it. Do you have any build errors?

Comment: Default path is setup properly. -- No build errors that are in my face. Its odd. Very odd. Last message I got was Lint Finished in 2.29s then it went back to command prompt.

Comment: for testing just create a new empty project and see the output of it?

Comment: I built the app using cordova commands (cordova run android --device) instead and then it generated the APK. Which I then installed. Runs like a charm!

Comment: Awsome :) Nice to see we have another option too :)

Comment: Yeah but now i have an issue getting ionic serve to run on any other apps but this one. With everything closed out and no others servers running. Yet it works fine on the app I just built. #confused.

Comment: Oh.. Can't you just try the one which I told you using `Ionic` commands only? new project .....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139670/discussion-between-codemonkeyalx-and-sampath).

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if that command still works, but this worked for me

ionic cordova build --debug android